# Blank page with react build when refresh it on other than home route

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, deployment, react-router

I have recently buid the react application and deployed it on firebase hosting.

The issue I face that web app work fine at [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/) and on navigation it also work fine for example it work fine when I **navigate** to **[www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login)**. But when I **refresh browser at [www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login)** than I get the error that

> This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the
> current directory or 404.html in the root directory.

Is there a way this issue can be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how firebase would accomplish this, but the general gist is that the server needs to redirect page requests for nested pages to the root `index.html` file so the React app can load/mount and then handle the routing internally. React app are effectively Single Page Apps afterall.

Comment: So it will be better if i create application with server side application, where routing handle by the server, because Firebase i believe only consider index html

Comment: Only if that suites your needs. Read over the create-react-app [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#firebase) for Firebase to see if that explains anything further.

Comment: I found the solution by updating firebase.json 
{  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution  by updating `firebase.json` as

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "build",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }]
    }
}
```

Here rewrites will direct all the requests from URLs to the `index.html` file.